# Como hacer un Split en Python con un texto con patrones

Tags: python, excel, string, split, data

Hola mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo Python que lea unos datos de un Excel que tiene el siguiete formato:

```
code_id,name,description,code_relation
www.dataware.org@444,nameA,Texto
Text Text,"code(RR)
www.dataware.org@555,nameB,LITLE TEXT,"code(FF)
www.dataware.org@666,nameC,
Texto
Text
Text
,"code(YY)
```

Los datos empiezan por una pagina web seguida de @id y terminan con "code(??)

Como puedo hacer una función en python para hacer un Slipt y optener los datos de la siguiente manera:

id,name,description

El resultado para el anterior seria

```
vector = 
[
"
@444,nameA,Texto
    Text Text,
",
"
@555,nameB,LITLE TEXT
",
"
@666,nameC,
    Texto
    Text
    Text
"
]
```

Lo que necesito es un split que me obtenga el texto intermedio entre:

- www.dataware.org@
- ,"code(??)

Agredecieria su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que es un único texto, puedes usar expresiones regulares para encontrar el primer match con la URL, después usa texto para encontrar el code y después igualas el texto a donde termino el code. Es deci quitas el texto que ya has usado y vuelves a iterar hasta que ya no haya más matches.

```
import re

text = """
    www.dataware.org@444,nameA,Texto
    'Text Text,"code(RR)
    www.dataware.org@555,nameB,LITLE TEXT,"code(FF)
    www.dataware.org@666,nameC,
    Texto
    Text
    Text
    ,"code(YY)
"""

vectors = []

while text:
    web = re.search('www\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+@', text)
    code = re.search('code\([a-zA-Z]{2}\)', text)
    if web and code:
        vectors.append(text[web.end():code.start()])
        text = text[code.end():]
    else:
        text = None
print(vectors)
```

Comment: Hola, Muchas gracias por tu comentario solo hay 2 inconvenientes: el texts[] en realidad no es un vector de strings... En realidad es un texto plano con: saltos de linea y tabulaciones.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta entonces, básicamente la idea es la misma, usar expresiones regulares, pero ahora con un único texto

Comment: Muchas gracias caballero... Sos un genio de la programación.